# ¿Hay algún término nacido en el mundo de los videojuegos que se haya incorporado al DLE?

Tags: definiciones, vocabulario-técnico, dle, juegos

Últimamente a mi hijo mayor le ha dado por jugar al Super Mario Bros original (sí, el de 1985). Tanto en este como en multitud de otros juegos de la época el jugador dispone de tres *vidas* para completar el juego (o las que sean). En este contexto, se podría definir *vida* como "cada uno de los intentos de que dispone un jugador para completar un videojuego". Esta definición estuvo vigente una temporada, hasta que los juegos empezaron a tener la posibilidad de guardar las partidas, y los videojuegos redefinieron dicho concepto para pasar a ser una especie de barra de energía que cuando se agota el personaje muere. Así, se pueden decir cosas como "qué poca *vida* me queda" o "tengo la *vida* por la mitad".

Sin embargo, en la entrada para *[vida](https://dle.rae.es/vida)* del DLE no hay nada referente al mundo de los videojuegos, aunque la primera acepción podría encajar, dado que es bastante genérica:

> 1. f. Fuerza o actividad esencial mediante la que obra el ser que la posee.

Se podría decir que la barra de vida del personaje es lo que le confiere (figuradamente) su fuerza para obrar.

Sin embargo, echo en falta esa acepción de "intento", cosa lógica por otro lado si consideramos que dicho concepto de *vida* no se ha popularizado más allá del ámbito de los videojuegos. Del mismo modo, no hay ninguna acepción en el verbo *[matar](https://dle.rae.es/matar)* que encaje con el hecho de perder una de las vidas de los videojuegos.

En los últimos años se han popularizado en este ámbito multitud de términos, desde *[arcade](http://www.gamerdic.es/termino/arcade)* como máquina recreativa o juego similar, hasta *[zonear](http://www.gamerdic.es/termino/zonear)* como ganar distancia de terreno contra el rival cuando se posee una ventaja en general. Ninguna de ellas la veo incluida en el DLE (de hecho muchos son anglicismos adaptados), entiendo que el contexto de aplicación y la alta posibilidad de que las voces que se van generando no lleguen a fijarse en el lenguaje hacen que no sea fácil su inclusión.

Sin embargo, y profundizando un poco en este tema, ¿existe alguna voz incluida en el DLE que haya sido inequívocamente generada en el ámbito de los videojuegos?

---

*Nota: hablo en esta pregunta exclusivamente sobre videojuegos, no sobre informática en general.*

Comment: El curso pasado fui tutora de un trabajo de investigación ("treball de recerca") de bachillerato sobre la evolución narrativa de los videojuegos de tipo "role playing" (de un muy buen alumno, por tanto, fue un trabajo de gran calidad). Se tuvo que recurrir a una enorme cantidad de anglicismos. No me vienen a la mente palabras específicas de este ámbito que puedan estar incorporadas en el DLE, pero echaré un vistazo al trabajo, aunque está escrito en catalán.

Answer (score 6):

Quizás [**videoconsola**](https://dle.rae.es/videoconsola#NvLRw0n):

> 1. f. Dispositivo electrónico que, conectado a una pantalla, permite jugar con videojuegos mediante mandos apropiados.

o

[**videojuego**](https://dle.rae.es/videojuego?m=form):

> 1. m. Juego electrónico que se visualiza en una pantalla.
> 2. m. Dispositivo electrónico que permite, mediante mandos apropiados, simular juegos en las pantallas de un televisor, una computadora u otro dispositivo electrónico.

Por otro lado, el diccionario de **María Moliner** recoge:

> **Marciano**:
>   3 m. inf. Personaje o figura de los videojuegos que se mueve y al que, generalmente, hay que destruir: ‘Matar marcianos’. (*) (pl.) Videojuego en el que aparece este tipo de personajes o figuras: ‘Jugar a los marcianos’